# Subset dataframe using logicals in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm trying to subset a dataframe using logical operators on the day of the year, and I wonder why the following doesn't work.

```
num <- c(11,22,33,44)
day.of.yr <- c(31,32,33,34)

dframe <- data.frame(num,day.of.yr)

  num day.of.yr
1  11        31
2  22        32
3  33        33
4  44        34

target.days <- c(32,34)

# works
test1 <-dframe[(day.of.yr==target.days[1] | day.of.yr==target.days[2]),]

  num day.of.yr
2  22        32
4  44        34

# doesn't work
test2 <- dframe[day.of.yr==target.days,]

  num day.of.yr
4  44        34
```

When I try it on a real dataset, R also outputs just a subset of what I want it to output, with this warning message:

```
Warning message:
In dframe$day.of.yr == target.days :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

It would be nice to have a short-cut way of specifying multiple rows of a dataframe based on the values in one column. I've tried a few different ways, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%in%`, like so:

```
subset(dframe, day.of.yr %in% target.days)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I like to avoid using subset() if I can, though, because of the warning in the help file: "This is a convenience function.... For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, ..."

Comment: Of course, the translation is `dframe[dframe$day.of.yr %in% dframe$target.days, ]`.

Comment: Actually, this works instead: `dframe[dframe$day.of.yr %in% target.days, ]`